# How to restore configuration settings in PyCharm if you create a new project over the same name as previous project name in the same location

Tags: pycharm, jetbrains-ide

I am using PyCharm and created a new project in the same place and with the same name as a previous project, but setting a different interpreter.

Now when I look in PyCharm it seems that the long list of configuration setups I used to have, have now disappeared, which includes all the environmental variables of each config setup.

I was wondering if there is a way to restore all my configuration settings from the previous project that also had the same name as the new one I created ?

Comment: 1) Project specific settings are stored in `.idea` subfolder (e.g. `PROJECT_ROOT/.idea`). The project name means nothing. If you have deleted that folder .. then yes, configure it all again as PyCharm does not store project-specific elsewhere (except your local workspace setup (opened files; window sizes -- this kind of stuff that has little value not on this machine), that is linked by the project ID that is different for every project).

Comment: 2) IDE wide config is stored elsewhere -- see https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/project-and-ide-settings.html and https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/directories-used-by-the-ide-to-store-settings-caches-plugins-and-logs.html. P.S. If IDE was installed via JetBrains ToolBox App then it can manage these settings differently (store in a different location). You should access them via ToolBox App (under gear icon for that app AFAIK)